# jQuery if url 2nd segment has hash do, else do nothing

Tags: jquery

So basically i want run the code only if url looks like this: `www.example.com/#page` otherwise do not run the jquery like `example: www.example.com/whatever/#page, www.example.com/whatever/whatever#page` etc..,

my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    if(window.location.hash == '#page'){alert('success');}
});
```

currently it alerts every url that contains #page. Any suggestion thanks!

Comment: your question isn't clear. do you want to check if a url has a path AND a hash?

Comment: would you want it to trigger if the url is `www.example.com/sample#page` ?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how a hash works. A url is a base domain, then a path, then a hash. You can't have a hash in more that one section of the path, only at the very end.

Comment: Are you saying only do _something_ if the `#` appears after the first `/` but before any second or subsequent `/`? (Are your last two example urls "valid" to do _something_, or "invalid"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
$(window).load(function(){
if(document.location.toString().indexOf('/#page')!=-1){alert('success');}
});
```

Comment: You could use `/#` to avoid having to rewrite it for every different `#page`

Answer (score 0):

check [window.location.pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location)

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/sample/sample" && window.location.hash == "#page")
```

or whatever permutation of that works for you

if you're looking to do it based on the depth of the path, lets say, alert only on pages that are at least two deep on the pathname, then you need to split the pathname

```
window.location.pathname.split("/").length //this is the depth of the url
```

So to combine the two ideas and fit your example,

```
var depth = window.location.pathname.split("/").length;
// pathname starts with a /, which adds one to the length of the array, so subtract
depth = depth -1;

// now run our checks
if (depth == 2 && window.location.hash == "#page") alert("success!");
else alert ("failure!");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var test = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/#page';
    if(test == location){alert('success');}
});
```